# Connecting Couchbase with Apache Drill

Tags: jdbc, database-connection, couchbase, apache-drill, simba

I am trying to connect using jdbc connection (the driver here: https://github.com/jdbc-json/jdbc-cb) apache drill with couchbase.

My storage configuration is:

```
{
    "type": "jdbc",
    "driver": "com.couchbase.jdbc",
    "url": "jdbc:couchbase://ip_address:8093/database",
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password",
    "enabled": true
}
```

I put the driver in "3rdparty" folder but I can't create the storage.

I have a jdbc connection for mysql that works.

I made other try with:

```
{
    "type": "jdbc",
    "driver": "com.simba.couchbase.jdbc41.Driver",
    "url": "jdbc:couchbase://localhost:8093/cluster_name",
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password",
    "enabled": true
}
```

I tried also with " com.simba.couchbase.jdbc4.Driver ".

I have a license for 20 days. I put the drivers an the license in "3rdparty" folder (folder for connectors in Apache Drill) and restarted the server.

The error is:  "Please retry: error (unable to create/ update storage) "

Any idea about what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please take a look in logs. They will contain more verbose error description which will help to identify the root cause.

Comment: The error that I get looking is: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data. I tried to add 'drill.exec.sys.store.provider.local.path = "CouchbaseJDBC41.jar"' in "drill-override.conf" but doesn't work again.

Comment: Hi @GonzaloColinoAlonso did you find solution for this? ```{
    "type": "jdbc",
    "driver": "com.simba.couchbase.jdbc41.Driver",
    "url": "jdbc:couchbase://localhost:8093/LifeAsia;AuthMech=1",
    "CredFile":"C://Program%20Files//apache-drill-1.16.0//jars//Couchbase_JDBC_Credentials.json",
    "enabled": true
}```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Simba JDBC Driver:**

Try this way it will work. I have done same thing which i mentioned here it is work for me.

```
{
  "type": "jdbc",
  "driver": "com.simba.couchbase.jdbc41.Driver",
  "url": "jdbc:couchbase://localhost:8093/LifeAsia;AuthMech=1;CredFile=C:/Program Files/apache-drill-1.16.0/jars/3rdparty/Couchbase_JDBC_Credentials.json",
  "username": null,
  "password": null,
  "caseInsensitiveTableNames": false,
  "enabled": true
}
```

Couchbase_JDBC_Credentials.json file contains array of user credentials such as username and password.

```
[{"user": "Administrator", "pass":"password"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using CData JDBC driver:**

Configure this json on your drill UI storage location http://localhost:8047/storage/couchbase_cdata_config

```
{
  "type": "jdbc",
  "driver": "cdata.jdbc.couchbase.CouchbaseDriver",
  "url": "jdbc:couchbase:UseConnectionPooling=true;Server='http://localhost';",
  "username": "Administrator",
  "password": "password",
  "caseInsensitiveTableNames": false,
  "enabled": true
}
```

Before that you should make sure copied JDBC driver and licence files to 3rdparty folder on drill location

[image]